# Stripping non printable characters from a string in python?

Tags: python, pycharm, html-parsing, python-3.4

So currently I am trying to find out how many times a specific word appears on a page.

My Python code has this:

> > print(len(re.findall(secondAnswer, page)))
> >
> > > 0

Upon careful analysis, I noticed that 
print(secondAnswer) is giving me a different answer "Pacific"

from print(ascii(secondAnswer)) 'Paci\ufb01c'

I have a feeling that my secondAnswer value in len(re.findall(secondAnswer, page)) is using 'Paci\ufb01c' instead and thus not finding any matches on the page.

Can someone give me any tips on how to solve this?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode character `fb01` is the [ﬁ ligature](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm). That is, it's a single character as far as Python is concerned, but appears as two (tied) characters when displayed.

To decompose ligatures into their separate characters, you can use [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). For example:

```
page = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", page)
```

Or in this specific case, you could write your regex to accept the ligature as an alternate for the `fi` character sequence, for example by using alternation with a non-capturing group: `paci(?:fi|ﬁ)c`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by how I would write my "regex to accept the ligature as an alternate for the fi character sequence" Sorry, I'm  fairly new to programming.

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, so where do I put the non-capturing group? I'm using PyCharm with my script.

Comment: I've tried to Google non-capturing groups but haven't understood much.

Comment: It's shown right in my answer. The `(?:....)` construction is a non-capturing group.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!